# debug a project.json command in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have the following entry in project.json:

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  }
```

I have until now been running 'dnx web' on the command line to start up my server. However, I would like to start it in such a way that I can debug (i.e. execution will hit the breakpoints that I set). How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your startup project of your solution is pointing at a project that can be started by one of the commands you have in project.json. If it is, then the command will appear in the start menu at the top of visual studio so that you can start it in debug mode.